# Select Single Field in two Column (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

We are using **Mysql Database** and we have Single tables that is **employee_transaction**.

**employee_transaction** table

```
id |  employee_id | date            | transaction_type
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 2015-01-01      | 1
2  | 1            | 2015-07-01      | 1 
3  | 1            | 2015-12-31      | 0
4  | 2            | 2014-02-01      | 1 
5  | 1            | 2016-04-01      | 1
6  | 2            | 2014-11-30      | 0
7  | 1            | 2016-08-01      | 1
8  | 1            | 2016-10-31      | 0
```

And so on.

To get the proper Result, the following Conditions need to be satisfied :-

- First transaction_type of any employee is always 1.
- Any Employee cannot have Consecutive transaction_type=0.
- The result of two consecutive transaction_type are below.These
  results is for one Employee

  1. **If both Transaction_type=1.**
     Then start_date=first transaction date, end_date= second transaction date-1 and transaction_type=1.
  2. **If first Transaction_type=1 and next transaction_type=0.** Then
     start_date=first transaction date, end_date= second transaction date
     and transaction_type=1.
  3. **If first Transaction_type=0 and next transaction_type=1.** Then
     start_date=first transaction date+1, end_date= second transaction
     date-1 and transaction_type=0.
  4. **If No transaction is found after transaction_type=0.** Then
     start_date=first transaction date+1, end_date=  Null and
     transaction_type=0.

We need the **Query** of following output from the **employee_transaction**  table.

```
  employee_id |  start_date     | end_date       | transaction_type
------------------------------------------------------
 1            | 2015-01-01      | 2015-06-30     | 1
 1            | 2015-07-01      | 2015-12-31     | 1 
 1            | 2016-01-01      | 2016-03-31     | 0
 1            | 2016-04-01      | 2016-07-31     | 1
 1            | 2016-08-01      | 2016-10-31     | 1
 1            | 2016-11-01      | (Null)         | 0 
 2            | 2014-02-01      | 2014-11-30     | 1
```

Thanks in advance.

If you have any concerns/clarification required, revert me.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Also, with the data you have provided `order by employee_id, start_date)` works.  The reasoning behind the rules is a bit unclear.  What do the transactions mean?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff , I have update all the details in the question. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Refer this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query/333953#333953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the next date, next transaction_type (ordered by date) per employee_id using a correlated subquery. Then use a `case` expression per the conditions mentioned.

```
select employee_id
,case when (transaction_type=0 and nxt_t_type=1) or (transaction_type=0 and nxt_t_type is null) then dt+interval '1' day
 else dt
 end as dt
,case when nxt_t_type=1 then nxt_dt-interval '1' day 
      when transaction_type=1 and nxt_t_type=0 then nxt_dt
      when transaction_type=0 and nxt_t_type is null then null
 end as nxt_dt
,transaction_type
from (select t1.*
      ,(select t2.dt from t t2 where t1.employee_id=t2.employee_id and t2.dt > t1.dt 
        order by t2.dt limit 1) as nxt_dt
      ,(select t2.transaction_type from t t2 where t1.employee_id=t2.employee_id and t2.dt > t1.dt 
        order by t2.dt limit 1) as nxt_t_type
      from t t1
     ) x
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/ALTY86334)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I know this is bad database design but changing the database. If  we can get result. This will really helpful for us.

Comment: Hi Again, As in the provided scenario the date is in the ordered , if they are not in the ordered then what we need to do. We need the same Result as you have provided to Me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query using correlated subqueries to join the sequential date and status information for each employee:

```
select
    f.emp_id, f.trans_date, f.trans_type,
    (select trans_date from emp_trans
    where emp_id=f.emp_id and trans_date = (select min(trans_date)
                                       from emp_trans where emp_id=f.emp_id
                                       and trans_date > f.trans_date)
    ) as end_trans_date,
    (select trans_type from emp_trans
    where emp_id=f.emp_id and trans_date = (select min(trans_date)
                                       from emp_trans where emp_id=f.emp_id
                                       and trans_date > f.trans_date)
    ) as end_trans_type
from emp_trans as f;
```